# RegExp - match from root or root + 1 subdir

Tags: regex, perl

I'm checking an ZIP-Archive in perl if the containing folder/structure is fine or not. Till now, the root directory contained a sourcen directory `/sourcen`. RegExp `^sourcen` did this for me.

Now I have a new case. The root directory might contain one subdir before sourcen-dir so it can look like this:

```
/sourcen
/SUBDIR/sourcen
```

but **it may not have more then one subdir** like this:

```
/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/sourcen
/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/sourcen
/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/SUBDIR/sourcen
...
```

Is it possible to use RegExp to validate sourcen dir is in root or only one subdir 'lower'?

Comment: I don't want to get only the last part of the string checked. I have to verify that there is max 1 subdir after root before my sourcen dir exists. Imo this makes it different then just looking for the last match like they do on filenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for `/sourcen` or `/other/sourcen`

```
$dir =~ m{^/ (?: [^/]+ / )? sourcen}x;
```

The `/x` allows spaces inside, for readability. The `{}` delimiters are used instead of the customary `//` so that we can use `/` in the pattern without escaping it. (Then we must have the `m` in front, which may be omitted with `//` delimiters.)

To be able to tell which is the case capture the whole thing (or its parts), by adding `()`.

---

We start (`^`) with `/` since this starts at root.

The `[^/]+` checks for any character which is not `/`, once or more times (`+`). So it matches a string of characters up to the first `/`. The construct `[^...]` is called *negated character class*. See it [in perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes) and [in perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes).
This is followed by literal `/`, needed with another directory.

All this is inside `(?: )` for grouping so that it can be made optional by the following `?` (zero times or once). The `?:` is there so that the whole pattern inside is not *captured* by `()`, since that is not needed here, but only grouped.

Thus the pattern `(?:[^/]+/)?` is the optional first directory.

Comment: This seems to work. Can you explain this for me to understand? I don't get the part of `(?:[^/]+/)`.

Comment: @Yaerox  Added an explanation.  I'll check and possibly edit more, but let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: @Yaerox I edited quite a bit, and added references.  I'll leave it for now, please let me know if more/better would be useful.